# Multiple factor Hull-While and yield curve deformation

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, factor-models, short-rate, hullwhite

I am currently studying rate models and I understand that the One-Factor model has some incompleteness: The yield-curve can only be shifted.
But I don’t understand what parameter controls this shift ( mean-rev, volatility, theta ..)
And concercing the multiple factors model ( For example a 2-factors hull-white) how can I change parameters to visualize a yield curve deformation ( inverted yield curve …)for example?
All your answers / materials are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any idea about it ?